# $a+\frac{1}{2M}\le\int^b_a xf(x)\,dx\le b-\frac{1}{2M}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f:[a,b] \to (0, +\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $\int^b_a f(x)\,dx =1 $ and $M=\max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)$. Prove that
> $$a+\frac{1}{2M}\le\int^b_a xf(x)\,dx\le b-\frac{1}{2M}.$$

This is the problem where I thought I could use that  $\int^b_a xf(x)\,dx =\frac{a+b}{2}$ because from the mean value theorem exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x)=(b-a)f(c)=1$ and also $f(c)<M$, so $1/(b-a)<M$, so
$$
\frac{1}{2M}+a< \frac{a+b}{2}<b-\frac{1}{2M}
$$
It is useful?It is another way I could prove this $$a+\frac{1}{2M}\le\int^b_a xf(x)\,dx\le b-\frac{1}{2M}.$$ ?

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Why would you think the integral is $\frac{a+b}2$????????????

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

make the substitution $$t=(a+b)-x$$

the integral becomes
$$I=\int_a^bxf(x)dx=$$
$$\int_a^b(a+b-t)f(a+b-t)dt=$$
$$(a+b)\int_a^bf(x)dx-\int_a^btf(a+b-t)dt$$

Comment: Thank you very much!I know how to solve it know.